# Recursive tr with Knockout JS and Jquery Template

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am going crazy trying to find a solution for my problem. I have a JS object which has a hierarchical structure and the level of hierarchy is unknown. Making use of JQuery template and Knockout JS i can get the tree structure with `<ul>` & `<li>` but my requirement is, for each child, I need to render a new `Row` in a `Table` So lets say my structure is:

```
{
    Name: 'First', 
    Total: 100,
    Set: [
        { 
            Name: 'First_1', Total: 30,
            Set: [{Name: 'First_1_1', Total: 10}, {Name: 'First_1_2', Total: 20}]  
        },
        { Name: 'First_2', Total: 0 }
    ]
}
```

The table should look like:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Total</th></tr>
    <tr><td>First</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First_1</td><td>30</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First_1_1</td><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First_1_2</td><td>20</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First_2</td><td>0</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Following is the fiddle I have come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/paragnair/xpsa4/

If I was using `ul` `li`, i could call the template recursively by using

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tree1', foreach: Set}"></ul>
```

but since my template itself starts with a `<tr>` I am not sure how do i call the template without writing a node with the `data-bind="template:{...}` part? The initial call will work because its on the `<tbody>` but I cannot have a `tbody` within a `tbody` to recursively call the template to render other `tr`.

I hope this explanation was sufficient. Let me know if you need more details. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recursively call a template from inside that template, that combined with the foreach's $data context property allows you do do what you're looking for... I'm terrible at explaining things so I updated your jsfiddle to do what you're looking for, http://jsfiddle.net/xpsa4/5/