# Jquery Knockout for/while loop inside template

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to create a tree structure table.

I have json array of the rows. One row can have other children rows.

```
[
   {
      "Name": "Row 1",
      "Depth": 1,
      "Rows": [{ "Name": "Row 1.1", "Depth": 2, "Rows": [] }]
   },
   {
      "Name":" Row 2",
      "Depth": 1,
      "Rows": []
   }
]
```

The template i have for a row (which doesn't work) looks like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="row-template">
   <tr>
       {{ for(var i = 1; i<= Depth; i++) { }}
          <td class='col'></td>
       {{/for}}

       <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
   </tr>
</script>
```

Is there any way of using repetitive statements inside knockout template so i can append the extra `n` columns i need for each row?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509324/recursive-tr-with-knockout-js-and-jquery-template?rq=1 Seems similar to what you want.

Comment: That solves nested templates problem, but is not what i need :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, in a MVVM point-of-view, you are over-skilling the markup;
So, my suggestion is: why you don't define an computed that returns an array of elements from the viewModel?

For example,
ViewModel

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Depth= ko.observable(10);


   self.DepthRepeated= ko.computed(function(){
       var ret = [];
       for(var i =0; i<self.Depth(); i++)
        ret.push(i);//note: very dirty way to create/populate an array!..but it's just for PoC

       return ret;

   });
}
```

Html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: DepthRepeated"></div>
```

(of course, in html part i have inserted a div, you will insert td/tr)